# How to pass ID instead of an object to listener in Laravel 9?

Tags: php, laravel, model, event-listener, laravel-9

I'm dispatching an event in User model class:

```
protected $dispatchesEvents = [
    'created' => UserCreated::class
];
```

My event class looks like:

```
class UserCreated
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithSockets, SerializesModels;

    public $user;

    /**
     * Create a new event instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct(User $user)
    {
        $this->user = $user;
    }
}
```

And listener class handle method:

```
public function handle(UserCreated $event)
{   
    Log::info($event->user);
    // Notify user, send e-mail 
}
```

How can I pass a newly created user ID, instead of object in my model class?
The problem is that in case of deleting user before running a job, the job fails - I have to add a condition in handle method which checks if a user exists. I do not have any idea how to handle that.

Comment: What stops you to make that condition? `$userExists = User::where(['id' => $event->user->id])->exists();`

Comment: This will not work. It will generate Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\ModelNotFoundException: No query results for model [App\Models\User] error, somewhere before listener handle method.

Comment: Then you have to show the code where/how do you call the event.

Comment: Event is called automatically in User model class - protected $dispatchesEvents

Comment: Yes, I see now. `$user` should be available in listener class for sure. On created event it is passed to listener class. Right? I don't see any relation to job class in code above. I am also not sure how user can be deleted before listener's handle method.

Answer (score 0):

The listener can access the user's ID by just using:

```
$event->user->id
```